# Two different POST requests are making use of the same variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, asynchronous, promise

I have a node app that receives a post request with multiple objects to add to a database and for object a series of things needs to happen that involve the dropbox api. It takes around 0.5 seconds to complete the full set of tasks for an object. This means that if i submit an array of 30 objects this can take 15 seconds.

When two clients post 30 objects their processing will overlap. I have a variable in the function where this happens that stores the issues with the handling of each case. However when to requests are posted and the running overlaps the errors from both post requests go into the same `issues` array. How do I get the server to call two separate versions of the bulkAdd function.

```
bulkAdd: async function (req, callback) {
  issues = []

  await req.reduce((promise, audit) => {
    // return promise.then(_ => dropbox_functions.createFolder(audit.scanner_ui)
    let globalData;
  return promise.then(_ => this.add(audit)
      .then((data)=> {globalData = data; return dropbox_functions.createFolder(data.ui, data)}, (error)=> {issues.push({audit: audit, error: 'There was an error adding this case to the database'}); console.log(error)})
        .then((data)=>{console.log(data, globalData);return dropbox_functions.checkScannerFolderExists(audit.scanner_ui)},(error)=>{issues.push({audit: globalData, error: 'There was an error creating the case folder in dropbox'})})
         .then((data)=>{return dropbox_functions.moveFolder(audit.scanner_ui, globalData.ui)},(error)=>{issues.push({audit: globalData, error: 'No data folder was found so an empty one was created'}); return dropbox_functions.createDataFolder(globalData.ui)})
          .then(()=>console.log(issues))
    );
  }, Promise.resolve()).catch(error => {console.log(error)});
  return(issues)
},
```

Comment: I bet the folks trying to help you, will immensely appreciate if you format your code and use one line per statement or expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem has to do with scope and closure:

`issues = []`

I'm guessing this variable was declared outside of the `bulkAdd` method. If it wasn't, declaring it without a `var` or `let` keyword is essentially putting the variable on the global scope.

You need a variable that's locally scoped to the method:

```
bulkAdd: async function (req, callback) {
  let issues = [];
```